# Python in XML: Getting text from grandchildren

Tags: python, xml, parsing, parent-child, kml

I'm quite novice in programming but I believe the data I'm looking for is quite easy to get, however I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

My XML has several parents and each have of course their children with siblings and siblings with children. I am trying to reach a specific grandchild where one of its siblings has a specific word in a certain tag.

The XML (actually a KML) looks like this:

```
<Folder>
    <name> Run-1</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name> run 1</name>
        <Snippet></Snippet>
        <styleUrl>#flightline</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <extrude>0</extrude>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>54.72664746,24.91070844,2008 54.76968330,24.91068150,2008
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Each folder named Run-X can have an infinite number of placemarks.

I want the name of each folder and the coordinates in the (there is only one) placemark containing the the `<styleUrl>#flightline</styleUrl>` ONLY.

That would build me a list of the run number and the 'flight line' coordinates.

Of course I am trying the python and w3 schools tutorials and I understand the basics but I can't seem to put it all together. Do I need a for loop to reach each child and a nested loop to reach every sub-child? Or can I just look for tags throughout the tree and get the coordinates value IF there is a `<styleUrl>#flightline</styleUrl>` tag?

I have been playing around with root.iter and root.findall but I can't seem to get any kind of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about following? Assuming your kml data resides in `data.xml`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

result = OrderedDict()
for folder in root.iter('Folder'):
    for placemark in folder.findall('Placemark'):
        if placemark.find('styleUrl').text == '#flightline':
            result[folder.find('name').text.strip()] = placemark.find('LineString/coordinates').text.strip()

print(result)
```

Comment: I saw i forgot to remove the </kml> tag in the end. Once I did that your code worked and indeed popped out the numbers. Only problem is, they are in a random order. Any way around that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by random order? its a dict, so will be based on hash. What order you are looking for?

Comment: Well, your code returns: ' Run-43': '54.23892268,24.35882803,2008 54.75827114,24.35912361,2008\n\t\t\t', ' Run-42': '54.23887394,24.37195836,2008 54.75827609,24.37225835,2008\n\t\t\t', ' Run-41': '54.23882504,24.38508867,2008 54.75828107,24.38538405,2008\n\t\t\t', ' Run-40': '54.23881558,24.39821066,2008 54.75832520,24.39851933,2008\n\t\t\t', ' Run-47': etc..

As you see the runs are in random order. I tried adjusting you code but again it's not printing anything. I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I thought I'dd print the values as it is scanning.

Comment: Why doesn't anything I write work...

`for folder in root.iter('folder'):
    for placemark in folder.findall('Placemark'):
        if placemark.find('styleUrl').text == '#flightline':
            flightLine = placemark.find('name').text
            print('Flightline: ' + str(lightLine))
            coordinates = placemark.find('LineString/coordinates').text
            print coordinates`

Comment: Ah ok you want the result as it was added or scanned. Then you need to use OrderedDict. I've updated the answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help. I found a solution based on to your code:

```
for folder in root.iter('Folder'):
for placemark in folder.findall('Placemark'):
    if placemark.find('styleUrl').text == '#flightline':
        runLine = folder.find('name').text[5:]
        startLat = placemark.find('LineString/coordinates').text[:11]
        startLong = placemark.find('LineString/coordinates').text[12:23]
        endLat = placemark.find('LineString/coordinates').text[29:40]
        endLong = placemark.find('LineString/coordinates').text[41:52]
        print ('Flightline: ' + runLine + ', coordinates start: ' + startLat + ' ' + startLong + '. Coordinates end: ' + endLat + ' ' + endLong + '.')
```

In case you are wondering, I'm trying to read files outputted by an aerial survey program (flightlines are lines flown to take pictures) and create a csv and flight plan file for the GPS in the aircraft to read so it can fly them automatically.

Now I need to find a way to remove the `<kml> </kml>` tags from the intial .kml file (on whatever line they might be) and only then open and parse it, output the line number and coordinates (with custom name) according to the flightline in a CSV and also output another flightplan file in a Garmin specific format. At least now I know how to scan the file. Thanks again Sir!

Comment: Glad it helped and I see you are doing more of data massaging after you identify the right Run. If you think my answer helped and that is what you were looking for, would be great if you can accept the answer/upvote it.

Comment: Now my problem is to remove the kml tags. Or can I adjust the code so it ignores then as parent? What would be easiest?

The original file looks like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">

<Document>
 <name>BoxC_AbuDhabi</name>` etc with </kml> all the way at the end.
I tried `##for kml in root.findall('kml'):
##  root.remove(kml)` but then kml is not defined...

Comment: well depending upon what's the structure and depth of tags, you can change the expression in findall methods. Without having the exact structure, I can help you much, but you can expand/edit/enrich the code which I provided based on the actual structure of your file. At least now you know how to parse the xml and how to locate the tags of interest